# Programmatically Add the "+" Button to a UIToolbar

Tags: swift, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have been having some trouble with adding a "+" button to a UIToolbar programmatically. Here is my code:

```
self.tableView.editing = false
    var toolbar: UIToolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)
    toolbar.items = [self.editButtonItem()]
    self.view.addSubview(toolbar)
```

I'd like to add something like

```
self.addButtonItem()
```

to the array with

```
self.editButtonItem()
```

. Sadly, I do not know the syntax and I cannot find it anywhere.

Any response is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add:

```
UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSustemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Add, target: self, action: Selector("addFunction'sName"))
```

To the array